# How to insert rows into a geodatabase bypassing an active edit session

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.3, c#, file-geodatabase, add-in

I'm developing an ArcMap addin with ArcObjects 10.3.1 SDK that needs to have an active edit session to work.

It creates new rows after a check process and stores them in a datatable into a file Geodatabase.

Like that:

```
// Initialize new row
errorRow = errorsTable.CreateRow();
// Fill row
...
// Commiting the new feature storage
errorRow.Store();
// Iterate over all check results then save edit session
((IWorkspaceEdit)m_featureWorkspace).StopEditing(true);
((IWorkspaceEdit)m_featureWorkspace).StartEditing(true);
```

My problem is I don't want the addin to rely on a programmatical save edits, since the user might be running other processes at this same edit session.

I then tried to use the method [`ExecuteSQL`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IWorkspace_ExecuteSQL.htm) from `IWorkspace` interface in hopes it would turn to be a direct insertion bypassing the edit session, but with no avail.

```
string sqlStatement = string.Format(new 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "INSERT INTO {0} VALUES (...);", ...);
((IWorkspace)m_featureWorkspace).ExecuteSQL(sqlStatement);

// Needs a save edits
((IWorkspaceEdit)m_featureWorkspace).StopEditing(true);
((IWorkspaceEdit)m_featureWorkspace).StartEditing(true);
```

Is there any way to programatically bypass an active edit session to insert rows into the database without having to mandatorily save a whole active edit session?

Comment: Not sure this is viable but have a look at creating [insert cursors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ITable_Insert.htm). Note the usage comment at the bottom of page.

Comment: @Hornbydd Nice one, thanks. I've tried it but neither Insert() bypasses edit session. I'd just upvote your comment if I could because its significant performance increase over Create() and Store() in this scope.

Comment: I am not aware of a way around an edit session. Does the user know this is running? Does the user know when it is finished? It may be best to let the user worry about saving the edits made by your addin.

Comment: @danielm Yeah but I didn't want to delegate the task to the user. I agree it is the only viable option in my scenario. Thanks.

Comment: Just thinking aloud. The typical work flow in ArcMap is that the user starts/ends the editing session. This is what is expected by the user. To silently start and stop editing seems like a dangerous route to go as a user could potentially corrupt the data without their knowledge. I think educating your user and providing a decent help file for your custom tool is a more robust way of doing things. It really is NO EFFORT to start\ stop editing, especially if they then go on and do complex editing of geometries?

Comment: Is your database versioned? If not, you do not need to use ArcObjects. Just use .NET to insert a row into the DB. The only caveat is to make sure you manage the ObjectID properly. ...sorry, this assumes it's an enterprise GDB.

Comment: The question is why do you need an edit session? It's only a standalone table, not participating in a topology or network, you should be able to use an insert cursor outside of an edit session **but** you might encounter geodatabase locks if the table is included in an edit session **unless** the database is an enterprise database (SDE), in which case I can understand the need to be editing - all operations in a *versioned* SDE database *must* be bracketed by an IEditOperation, which I don't see in your code, not just start/stop editing. Otherwise you could wait for OnSaveEdits to do your bit.

Comment: @Hornbydd I do understand this is not the proper way and I agree with you... @Brad It is a file GDB. @MichaelStimson It's a simple matter of ease and at the same time saving of code chopping when recovering the `IWorkspace`, instead of having the user to choose in a box dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Workaround**: I ended up adding my own edit session control in a custom toolbar. The user is asked if he wants to start an edit session, and save current edits or just close the addin when untoggling it.